# why I can't set mapView.showsUserLocation to YES in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios5, mkmapview

I have found here a similar old post:
[showsUserLocation does not display blue dot in iPhone 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552424/showsuserlocation-does-not-display-blue-dot-in-iphone-4-0)

I have this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];

    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    //[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;    
    NSLog(@"bool: %d", [mapView showsUserLocation]);

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[WhereamiViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhereamiViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Why does `NSLog(@"bool: %d", [mapView showsUserLocation])` show `0`, not `1`? Why can't I set it to `YES`?

Comment: can you post the log of `NSLog(@"map: %@ , %d", mapView, [mapView showsUserLocation]);` ?

Comment: where have you allocated the mapview..?

Comment: Are you testing on a device or the simulator?

Comment: I think you forgot to allocate the `mapView`.

Answer (score 0):

You application may have finished launching but maybe your view has not loaded. If the view hasn't loaded the mapView that is within it won't have either. Try moving the showsUserLocation code to viewDidLoad